# Spring Cloud or Spring Boot? what is right spring project for developing Biz API's?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

We are trying to build a new Business API layer in between UI and applications/services.

Which project in spring is best and will serve the needs for developing Biz Api's with restful services?

Is it `Spring Cloud` or `Spring Boot`?

Comment: From the [official project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/): "Spring Cloud builds on Spring Boot (...)"

Comment: Thank you. So, can I assume Spring Cloud project is the recommendation/way to build Business API.

Comment: I am still learning the two projects. So any information is helpful and appreciated

Answer (score 80):

Spring Boot is app-centric.  As @kryger said, Spring Cloud builds on boot.  It solves higher level problems, such as:

- Distributed configuration: How to configure every instance of all of your services (standard boot config files checked into git or svn and distributed via config server).
- Service registration and discovery: how to locate a specific instance of a service (using Netflix Eureka)
- Client Side load balancing: intelligently choose an instance of a service to use (using Netflix Ribbon) via a smart algorithm such as: round robin or response time
- Plug into Ribbon via Spring Rest Template or Netflix Feign.
- Serve all assets and api's via a proxy that is plugged into service discovery and load balancing (Netflix Zuul).
- Stop cascading api failures with the Circuit Breaker pattern via Netflix Hystrix and visualize the health of all circuits with the Hystrix Dashboard.
- Send commands to all or some services via a lightweight message bus.
- Use oauth2 to protect resources
- and other things I've probably forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

Well the choice is yours based upon the need .

If you have multiple services and need service configuration , discovery , fault tolerant etc. then use Spring cloud features using spring boot app. Also cloud native libraries are also available for the dedicated Cloud services providers .

If you have just a single service and you are aware of your hosting mechanism then just a simple spring boot App is good enough .

Comment: My upvote was based on the second paragraph, especially the phrase "if (...) you are aware of your host mechanism". Good point.